# Allow IIS 7.5 access to certificates private key at Windows 2008 R2 x64

Tags: iis, ssl, permissions, certificate

all

I'm trying to allow my IIS application get access to private key in personal storage of local computer.

For this I open MMC, go to certificate, make right click on it and select 'All tasks' -> 'Manage Private Keys'. After it I look a user “IIS apppool\DeafultAppPool” and after it next window appears

http://i.piccy.info/i7/d513f1d506db7ac204ffb9750c9d0271/4-57-649/39413546/Before.png

I see that user appears at the list and after I click 'Apply' button. User disappears from list and window looks like this

http://i.piccy.info/i7/f5f533361519458bbc2d0d68c898996e/4-57-649/35214190/After.png

No user added to permissions list and my program does not have access to certificates private key. Am I doing something wrong? Or there is a bug at Windows?

Comment: Did you see this post on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609859/how-to-give-asp-net-access-to-a-private-key-in-a-certificate-in-the-certificate

Comment: Yes, I've already seen it. Moreover I do the same as written there but have issue: my permissions are not saved and I can't inderstand why (see images at my post).